# Why does this reg exp always succeed for the numerics?

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

I have a regular expression that searches for the special characters.

When I do a search on numerics, e.g. 3, I always get 0, when I'd expect to get -1.

```
'3'.search(/[!\"£\$%\^&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\};:@\'#\\|<,\.>\/\?]/)
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: There are way too many unnecessary backslashes...

Comment: Just started to use the regular expressions. Do you mind giving an example on how you'd simplify this? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\)-_
```

This causes the character class to include all characters between `)` and `_`, i.e. `)*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`. `3` is in one of these.

The `-` should be placed at the beginning or end, so that it won't be counted as a special character. Also, besides `\`, `[`, `]` and `/`, there's no need to escape anything in a character class.

```
/[-!"£$%^&*()_+=\[\]{};:@'#\\|<,.>\/?]/
```

(Technically the `[` doesn't need to be escaped either, but for consistency I prefer to escape it. Also, you could match a `-` in the middle if you escape it `\-`.)